# FadeOut a body iframe/object with jquery

Tags: jquery, object, iframe, fadeout

I want to fadeOut an iframe content when I click in a link but I can´t find the way to do it!.

This is my code that is not working:

```
<object type="text/html" data="page.html" id="framecontent" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mylink a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#framecontent").find("body").fadeOut('slow', redirectPage);
    });
    function redirectPage() {
        $("#framecontent").attr("data", linkLocation);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: May I ask why you would be trying to fade out the body but not the entire iFrame? After all, all viewable HTML is contained in the body, so couldn't you achieve the same effect by just fading out the iFrame?

Comment: Well I'm trying to make a simple FadeOut and FadeIn effect when I click in diferents links. So the idea was click on one link and this should fadeOut and after this load the page cliked that has:
    $(document).ready(function() {$("body").fadeIn('slow');});

Answer (score 0):

`fadeOut()` doesn't seem to work on `<object>` but if you use `<iframe>` is should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed the object to an iFrame and implemented the code to fade out the iFrame, change the page, and fade in the iFrame after it loads - is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/edapU/2

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com" id="framecontent" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
<div id="mylink">
    <a href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a><br/>
    <a href="http://www.car.com">Car.com</a><br/>
    <a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mylink a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#framecontent").fadeOut('slow', redirectPage);
    });
    function redirectPage() {
        $("#framecontent").attr("src", linkLocation).load(function(){$(this).fadeIn('slow');});
    }
});
</script>
```